No response after +STARTUP boot (NINA-w152)
Device model: NINA-w152
I have been stuck on this problem for quite sometime, I have a NINA-w152 module according to the datasheet it has preloaded firmware and after booting up I have received +STARTUP message on the terminal console and sending any AT commanded which I don't have any OK's.
My current setup is UART without flow control (CTS is grounded).
If anyone has experience with u-blox NINA w-152.
-Checked UART lines
-Voltage levels are ok (3.6V)
-Disabled control Flow
-Check on Oscilloscope on the Tx lines of the NINA-w152 module and it is indeed running +3V
